# Build Type from another type's keys, generically

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a type that is based off another type's keys, but I don't know what those keys will be ahead of time. I do know that I can annotate the occasions when I need this type.

What I'm trying to express would behave like so:

```
import Patcher from '@/types/Patcher'

export default interface SinglePatchers<T> {
  [key: keyof T]: Patcher
}
```

However, the above syntax is invalid.

How may I construct this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Patch} from '@/store/singles/patcher'

export type SinglePatchers<T> = Record<keyof T, Patch>
```

The built in utility type 'Record' handles this scenario.